# Unable to log in SonarQube with admin/admin after upgrade

Tags: authentication, sonarqube

I use SonarQube and i upgraded in v7.3.

I am able to run SonarQube but I can't log in with Default Credential (admin/admin). I get this error message in logs (web.log) :

> 2018.09.14 14:46:23 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of      request /api/authentication/login failed
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeStartObject(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:626)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3893)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3231)
>     at
>   io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.toJson(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:354)
>     at
>   io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.base64UrlEncode(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:344)
>     at
>   io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:295)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtSerializer.encode(JwtSerializer.java:97)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtHttpHandler.generateToken(JwtHttpHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.JwtHttpHandler.generateToken(JwtHttpHandler.java:96)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.doFilter(LoginAction.java:103)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
>     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     ... 40 common frames omitted

I'm using the jdk 1.8.0 u181.
What's the problem ?

Comment: Is it a fresh install (=unzipping in a new directory) ? Which plugins have been installed in the directory extensions/plugins and which authentication mechanism is activated ? Thanks.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource Hi, for installation, I unzipped the folder of 7.3. I followed the instructions that i found on the SonarQube Website to upgrade (modify the files in conf folder, ...) and I copy and paste the source in the installation folder that I used for a previous version of SonarQube. I use the plugin sonar C# (v7.5.0.6605) and sonar-l10n-fr (v1.15). I' m sorry I don't know what kind of authentification mechanism is activate but to describe it, when I go on the page to log in, I fill the credentials (ex : admin/admin) and I received "Authentification failed" at each time I try

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource : when I see the logs (web.log) and activate the DEBUG trace, I can see this : **2018.09.17 11:41:44 DEBUG web[AWXm4inKus5y+IJ+AAAU][auth.event] login success [method|FORM][provider|LOCAL|local][IP|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|][login|admin]2018.09.17 11:41:44 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/authentication/login failed
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception...Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeStartObject(Ljava/lang/Object;)V...**

Comment: Try to reset the password with the following query on the database update users 
set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt= '6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' 
where login = 'admin'

Comment: @jckhan Thank's for the help but that's doesn't work. Now I get this error after the query : 2018.09.18 16:10:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] WebServer is operational
2018.09.18 16:10:42 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization of SonarQube done
2018.09.18 16:10:52 **ERROR** web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/authentication/login failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Invalid salt version**

Comment: That error comes from trying to update the database value with a not encrypted value . Did you copy the whole query ?

Comment: Yes I copied the whole query. I can see the changing in the database.

Comment: I suggest to install incrementally in order to spot the root cause. Start by running a fresh instance, without any custom plugins nor custom configuration. If everything is fine then you can follow the next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded out what was the issue (i think).

It was the French plugin which is not compatible with the 7.3 version. So when i runned SonarQube v7.3 with this plugin, it used the wrong version of many plugins in Sonar Server (i have seen plugins in version 6.7, not 7.3).

So I maked an installation again without any plugin and it works.

Thank you for your help.